# How to manage partitions in MariaDB with InnoDB tables?

Tags: innodb, mariadb, partitioning

I'd like to set up partitioning for the "time series" use case as in
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/partition-maintenance/.

However, I'd also like to control data directories. And I want the "max" or "future" partition as a *catch all* fallback.

So I start with (minimalist example):

```
CREATE TABLE partitioned (
  timestamp INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (timestamp)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
PARTITION BY RANGE (timestamp)
(
  PARTITION pstart VALUES LESS THAN (1) DATA DIRECTORY 'G:/MariaDB/partitions/start',
  PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (1577833200) DATA DIRECTORY 'G:/MariaDB/partitions/1',
  PARTITION pmax VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE DATA DIRECTORY 'G:/MariaDB/partitions/max'
);
```

Works as expected.

Now I want to add a new partition, splitting the "pmax" partition:

```
ALTER TABLE partitioned
  REORGANIZE PARTITION pmax INTO (
    PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (1609455600) DATA DIRECTORY 'G:/MariaDB/partitions/2',
    PARTITION pmax VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
);
```

This only kind of succeeds, as the `DATA DIRECTORY` clause is ignored, with a warning. So the result is useless. The "pmax" partition is now in the default data directory and the "p2" partition is in `G:\MariaDB\partitions\max`.

Specifying both data directories:

```
ALTER TABLE partitioned
  REORGANIZE PARTITION pmax INTO (
    PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (1609455600) DATA DIRECTORY 'G:/MariaDB/partitions/2',
    PARTITION pmax VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE DATA DIRECTORY 'G:/MariaDB/partitions/max'
);
```

gives two warnings, the "pmax" stays in its place now, but the "p2" partition is still created in that same directory.

`ADD PARTITION` doesn't work either, as it collides with `MAXVALUE` condition.

Any way around this?

MariaDB version 10.4.12

Comment: Suggest filing a bug with jira.mariadb.com

Comment: Thank you. Apparently, this is an open issue: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-14618. I added a comment there.

Comment: Good catch.  Did you upvote it?  I think they use that could in deciding when to get around to working on bugs/features.

Comment: Yes, I upvoted it. But it only has 4 votes so far.